# diff commnad not working "missing operand after `diff'"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, diff

In diff command am getting following error. Kindly assist how can I specify I want to see difference in two files:

```
#current_unavail=ranjith

root@iitmserver1 tmp]# cat /tmp/ran
ranjith
[root@iitmserver1 tmp]#

#test=$(cat /tmp/ran)

[root@iitmserver1 tmp]# diff `$current_unavail` `$test`
diff: missing operand after `diff'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
[root@iitmserver1 tmp]#
```

Comment: Quote your variables. `$current_unavail` would appear to have spaces in the filename (or isn't the name you expect it to be).

Comment: [root@iitmserver1 unavail_cn]# cat /tmp/unavail_cn.out
     iitmc07n24-ib0  unavail
     [root@iitmserver1 unavail_cn]#

     current_unavail=$(cat /tmp/unavail_cn.out)

Comment: `$current_unavail` is the *contents* of the current file? That's not going to work. Also it seems it does have a space there (update the post instead of putting things in comments so you can format them). Which is why you need to quote your variable but that isn't enough here because diff takes *files* as arguments.

Comment: Hi Etan, kindly have a look on my full code.. this we are using for sending mail, when node down.

Comment: Right `$last_unavail` is a filename. You pass that file to `diff`. `$current_unavail` is a string (of two "words"). You also pass that to diff (unquoted). The fact that `$current_unavail` is unquoted and more than one word is why you get the `extra operands` error. `diff` is seeing **three** arguments `iitmc07n24-ib0`, `unavail`, and the `$last_unavail` file. That's the first problem. Quote `"$current_unavail"` and that will go away. The second problem, however, is that you are trying to pass the files **contents** to diff directly but diff takes **filenames**. Use `/tmp/unavail_cn.out`.

Comment: That's assuming the contents of `$current_unavail` are what's in the `$last_unavail` filename. I can't quite tell in the mess of pipelines you have going on there.

Comment: just i added explication of above script. kindly look into it.

Comment: Can you break down your `diff` question to a base case? Also are you able to see any useful information when debugging. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

Comment: @ranjith **comments** are a good thing in scripts. They help make you logic much easier to follow for those willing to help.

Answer (score 2):

`diff` takes two *filenames* as arguments, where you appear to be passing in file *contents* as the first argument. You will want to change your script/commands to look more like:

```
current_unavail=/tmp/unavail_cn.out
result=$(diff $current_unavail /moes/home/pharthiphan/scripts/monitoring/unavail_cn/$last_unavail)
```

Alternatively, you can use [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to pass the output of a command into another command that is expecting a file. eg:

```
diff <(echo -e "foo\nbar") <(echo -e "foo\nbaz")
```

However, while good to know about, this would seem to be a needless level of complexity for your current problem.

Comment: [root@iitmserver1 ~]#  result=$(diff <(echo -e $current_unavail) <(echo -e /moes/home/pharthiphan/scripts/monitoring/unavail_cn/$last_unavail))
[root@iitmserver1 ~]# echo $result
1c1 < --- > /moes/home/pharthiphan/scripts/monitoring/unavail_cn/nodes_20150415_101602
[root@iitmserver1 ~]#
depends this o/p we follows  # if [ $? -eq 0 ]; always produce 1 o/p.. means difference is there. kindly look into our scripts in above. kindly assist.